# XmlDocument Exception: valor hexadecimal 0x1a, é um caractere inválido

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

Tenho um projeto que lê um XML gerado por outro programa na qual eu não tenho acesso ao código fonte. O problema é que o XML gerado vem com um caractere especial no final, e quando vou tentar ler o XML a *exception* é lançada.

Segue o código:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
   xmlDoc.Load(localMontaXML);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   erros.Add(ex.Message);
}
ErrorChecker.Check(erros);
```

Têm alguma forma de ignorar esse caractere?

Utilizo Windows Forms com .Net 3.5

Comment: Você poderia editar o arquivo com `StreamWriter` e remover esse caractere antes de abrir como um `XmlDocument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem sim cara, mas antes você deve considerar a possibilidade de o arquivo estar vindo corrompido ou algo do tipo. Se você tem certeza que este arquivo está íntegro, e que apenas existe um caractere inválido no final por alguma razão desconhecida (?), você pode jogar o arquivo em memória exceto o último caractere, obtendo o seu xml válido.

Existem duas formas que eu conheço de fazer isso. Observe o código a seguir:

**METODO 1**

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) // cria um stream de memória
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\sample.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
// abre o arquivo xml. No caso C:\sample.xml
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length]; // onde ficará o conteúdo do arquivo - 1
    fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length); // lê o arquivo
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length-1); // escreve tudo exceto o último byte (length - 1)

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // volta para o início do stream

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(ms); // carrega o arquivo em memória
    Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Value); // teste de leitura
}
```

**METODO 2**

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\sample.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
// cria um arquivo mapeado em memória a partir do seu FileStream
using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fs,"xml",fs.Length,MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read,null,System.IO.HandleInheritability.None,true)) 
{
    // cria um stream que enxerga até o final do arquivo - 1
    using (var str = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, fs.Length - 1, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read)) 
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(str); // lê a partir do stream
        Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Value);
    }
}
```

O segundo utiliza [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx).

Um detalhe é que estes métodos copiam o conteúdo do arquivo para a memória, não é a coisa mais performática do mundo então tome cuidado ao fazer isso com um XML grande, e nunca se esqueça dos `using` para "descartar" seus `Stream` após o uso.

Boa sorte e espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Boa resposta @Conrad Clark

Tenho uma terceira sugestao caso nao se saiba quantos caracteres a mais o ficheiro tem no fim.

`xmlDoc.LoadXml(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(localMontaXML, @"<[\w\W]+>").ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

No meu caso, o erro que ocorreu foi similar **hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character**, talvez a solução seja proxima, mudando apenas o caracter a ser substituido no final.

Quando ocorreu o erro estava assim:

```
xmlObj = new XmlDocument();
xmlObj.Load(arquivo.fullPath);
```

A correção foi:

```
StreamReader sr = arquivo.OpenText(); //carrega o texto do arquivo
string xmlText = sr.ReadToEnd(); //lê o texto do arquivo e salva na variavel xmlText
xmlText = xmlText.Replace("\0", string.Empty); // retira os caracteres nulos;
xmlObj = new XmlDocument(); // cria o xml
xmlObj.LoadXml(xmlText); // Carrega a string diretamente para ser lida como xml
```

Espero que possa ajudar.