# Lendo XML em C#

Tags: c#, xml

Sei que existe muito Post sobre como ler um arquivo `XML`, mas não achei nenhum que apresente o `XML` com a mesma estrutura que eu tenho.

Estou com o seguinte Código.

```
private void LeituraXML()
{

    //Criando objeto xml para abrir o arquivo de configuração

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    //Informando o caminho onde esta salvo o arquivo xml

    string cadastro = @"C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Tipo_Documentos.xml";
    doc.Load(cadastro);
    XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("data");

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
    {
       string teste1 = node.SelectSingleNode("tipo").InnerText;
       string teste2 = node.SelectSingleNode("metadata").InnerText;
    }
}
```

e com o `XML`

```
<service>
    <name>TiposDocumentaisEMetadados</name>
</service>
<message>
    <type>success</type>
<value/>
</message>
<data>
    <tipo codigo="7" name="Comprovante de Endereço">
      <metadata name="numero_documento" required="false" type="string" max_length="255"/>
      <metadata name="protocolo_processo" required="false" type="string" max_length="255"/>
      <metadata name="assunto" required="false" type="string" max_length="800"/>
      <metadata name="interessado" required="false" type="string" max_length="255"/>
      <metadata name="observacao" required="false" type="string" max_length="255"/>
      <metadata name="data_documento" required="true" type="date_time"/>
      <metadata name="login_autor" required="true" type="string" max_length="50"/>
    </tipo>
</data>
```

Eu preciso adicionar em variáveis o código e o `name` da TAGs `<tipo>` e a Tag `<metadata>` preciso apenas do `name`?

Comment: o seu xml é só isso mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode ler e gravar os dados utilizando a classe [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), para isso, você só precisa ter uma classe que represente o conteúdo do seu XML, vou usar como base a parte do XML que você postou.

Exemplo de classe baseado no seu XML:

```
public class Config
{
    public Service service { get; set; }
    public Message message{ get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public TipoData tipo { get; set; }
}

public class TipoData
{
    public int codigo { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<MetaData> metadata { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool required { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int max_length { get; set; }
}
```

Para serializar seu objeto e salvar em XML utilize:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
var localArquivo = "C:/arquivo.xml";
var xmlNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(localArquivo))
{
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, conteudo, xmlNamespaces);
}
```

E para deserializar o XML e utilizá-lo no seu código:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
var configuracao = new Config();
var localArquivo = "C:/arquivo.xml";

using (var textReader = new StreamReader(localDoArquivo))
{
    configuracao = (Config)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
}
```

Você irá utilizar as seguintes `usings`:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
```

Answer (score 3):

O arquivo [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) está mau formatado, precisa ter um tag `root` e por isso eu arrumei para responder a pergunta, adicionando o elemento `root` para leitura.

***Arquivo modificado:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <service>
    <name>TiposDocumentaisEMetadados</name>
  </service>
  <message>
    <type>success</type>
    <value/>
  </message>
  <data>
    <tipo codigo="7" name="Comprovante de Endereço">
      <metadata name="numero_documento" required="false" type="string" max_length="255"/>
      <metadata name="protocolo_processo" required="false" type="string" max_length="255"/>
      <metadata name="assunto" required="false" type="string" max_length="800"/>
      <metadata name="interessado" required="false" type="string" max_length="255"/>
      <metadata name="observacao" required="false" type="string" max_length="255"/>
      <metadata name="data_documento" required="true" type="date_time"/>
      <metadata name="login_autor" required="true" type="string" max_length="50"/>
    </tipo>
  </data>
</root>
```

***Código para leitura***

No [SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx) precisa passar o caminho completo que no caso atual começa do `root` e vai até `tipo` e depois a lista de `metadata`:

Exemplo dos caminhos:

> `//root//data//tipo`
>
> `//root//data//tipo//metadata`

e depois pegar os valores dos seus `atributos`, ***exemplo***:

```
private static void LeituraXML()
{           

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string cadastro = @"./base.xml";
    doc.Load(cadastro);
    XmlNode nodeListTipo = doc.SelectNodes("//root//data//tipo").Item(0);
    XmlNodeList nodeListMetadata = doc.SelectNodes("//root//data//tipo//metadata");

    String codigoTipo = nodeListTipo.Attributes["codigo"].Value;
    string nameTipo = nodeListTipo.Attributes["name"].Value;           

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeListMetadata)
    {
        string nameMetadata = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
        string requiredMetadata = node.Attributes["required"].Value;
        string typeMetadata = node.Attributes["type"].Value;
        string max_lengthMetadata = node.Attributes["max_length"].Value;                

        // aqui os dados se repetem e podem ser colocados
        // em uma coleção de uma determinada classe
        // exemplo List<Metadata> ex ....
    }
}
```

<sub>***Observação:*** observe os 3 comentários, dentro da estrutura de repetição `for`, o `metadata` são vários, então, dependendo da sua regra pode ser que precise utilizar uma lista de valores (coleção).</sub>

***Leitura***

- [Qual diferença xmldocument vs xmlwriter?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9362/qual-diferen%C3%A7a-xmldocument-vs-xmlwriter)
- [XmlDocument Exception: valor hexadecimal 0x1a, é um caractere inválido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5169/xmldocument-exception-valor-hexadecimal-0x1a-%C3%A9-um-caractere-inv%C3%A1lido)
- [Ler arquivo XML em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48892/ler-arquivo-xml-em-c)
- [Ler XML com XMLDocument em Delphi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92863/ler-xml-com-xmldocument-em-delphi)

***Referencias***

- [Classe XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método XmlNode.SelectNodes (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Writing XML with the XmlDocument class](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/)